# how to store element in array and get array length in C?

Tags: c

Below code is storing element in array but its not return the size.
how can i get the size of array ? if element insertion process is wrong then how can i achieve the same things in c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
char *names[] = {};
int main ()
{


  names[0] = "ashish1";
  names[3] = "ashish";
  printf("%s\n",names[0]);
  printf("%d",sizeof(names));
   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

ashish1
0
it should be 
ashish1
2

i want to append string into array

Comment: In C it's illegal to put empty braces as initializer. You need to specify at least one element or just simply its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is illegal in C. Braced initializer lists must contain at least one initializer. If this compiles for you, you are taking advantage of a compiler extension. (From memory, gcc treats this as a zero-sized array).

For your code to work you have to make it large enough:

```
char const *names[4];   // no initializer required, globals default to zero-initialized

int main()
{
    names[0] = "ashish1";
    names[3] = "ashish";
    printf("%s\n", names[0]);
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof names / sizeof names[0]);
}
```

The array size must be fixed at the time the array is declared; you cannot grow named arrays in C.  (You can grow dynamically-allocated arrays though).

Comment: thanks for reply. how can grow it if i want to make it dynamic

Comment: Then you use `malloc` (which takes a number of bytes, not a number of entries). You have to store the number of entries separately.  I'd advise learning from a book or other reference.

Comment: do you have any running example ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't allocate size for array of pointer,

```
names[0] = "ashish1";

in that time C compiler allocate memory to pointer so string starting address stored.
"ashish1" string stored on read only memory location.  
if you stored any data first allocate size to *names.
```